# update fails with "gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function."

Tags: apt, updates

I am new to Ubuntu and Kubernetes. When I try to configure a Kubernetes cluster the `update` command fails with following message:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err:9 ht#tps://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/i18n/Translation-en  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

<sup>(This is not complete output. I kept only the error messages.)</sup>

Can someone please help me understand and resolve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1018198/175814